# java.lang.Runtime exception "Cannot run program"

Tags: java, linux, unix, cat, runtime.exec

I am getting an exception like `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program cat /home/talha/* | grep -c TEXT_TO_SEARCH": error=2, No such file or directory` while executing the command below despite that **there are no issues when I execute the same command through the terminal.** I need to execute and return the output of the command below:

```
cat /home/talha/* | grep -c TEXT_TO_SEARCH
```

Here is the method used to execute commands using `Runtime` class:

```
public static String executeCommand(String command) {

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return output.toString();
}
```

Comment: specify the full path of the `cat` & `grep` commands.

Comment: but that command works as it is expected through the terminal (bash)

Comment: Well sure, that's because `$PATH` is defined so it knows to look for `cat` along `/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin` whatever.  Within the context of the Java Runtime, it does not have that environment.

Comment: Runtime.exec does not use a shell (like, say, `/bin/bash`);  it passes the command directly to the operating system.  This means wildcards like `*` and pipes (`|`) will not be understood, since `cat` (like all Unix commands) does not do any parsing of those characters.  You need to use something like `p = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", command).start();`, or, if for some bizarre reason you need to stick to using the obsolete Runtime.exec methods, `p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "bash", "-c", command });`.

Comment: Could you post your comment as an answer? Then, I'll be able to accept your answer as the solution of the problem. @VGR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Runtime.exec does not use a shell (like, say, `/bin/bash`);  it passes the command directly to the operating system.  This means wildcards like `*` and pipes (`|`) will not be understood, since `cat` (like all Unix commands) does not do any parsing of those characters.  You need to use something like

```
p = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", command).start();
```

or, if for some bizarre reason you need to stick to using the obsolete Runtime.exec methods:

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "bash", "-c", command });
```

If you are only running that cat/grep command, you should consider abandoning the use of an external process, since Java code can easily traverse a directory, read lines from each file, and match them against a regular expression:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("TEXT_TO_SEARCH");
Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();

long count = 0;

try (DirectoryStream<Path> dir =
    Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("/home/talha"))) {

    for (Path file : dir) {
        count += Files.lines(file, charset).filter(pattern.asPredicate()).count();
    }
}
```

**Update:** To recursively read all files in a tree, use [Files.walk](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-):

```
try (Stream<Path> tree =
    Files.walk(Paths.get("/home/talha")).filter(Files::isReadable)) {

    Iterator<Path> i = tree.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        Path file = i.next();
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(file, charset)) {
            count += lines.filter(pattern.asPredicate()).count();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: How can I **recursively** look up for the files under the root directory?

Comment: Updated answer.  Use the Files.walk method instead of a DirectoryStream.

Comment: Getting this exception: `java.nio.file.FileSystemException: Too many open files`

Comment: `Runtime.exec` (and also `ProcessBuilder`) does not run a shell unless you explictly say so, so by default globs, pipes and other redirections (`> >> < << <>` etc) don't work, nor do variable or process substitution or flowcontrol like `& && || if while` etc. But `exec(String)` as opposed to `exec(String[])` _does_ whitespace-tokenize the command, so the code posted should not give the particular exception posted. (PS: a _few_ Unix utilities do their own globbing such as `find` and `rsync`, and even their own piping such as `awk`.)

Comment: @talha06 Updated answer again.  Auto-closing the Stream returned by Files.lines should promptly close each file and should prevent the “Too many open files” error.

Answer (score 0):

`$PATH` is an environment variable that tells the system where to search for executable programs (it's a list of directories separated by colons). It is usually set in your `.bashrc` or `.cshrc` file but this is only loaded when you log in. When Java runs, `$PATH` is likely not set because the `rc` file is not executed automatically, so the system can't find programs without specifying exactly where they are. Try using `/bin/cat` or `/usr/bin/cat` instead of just `cat` and see if it works. If it does, `$PATH` is your problem. You can add `$PATH=/bin:/usr/bin` to your script or just leave it with the directory name specified (e.g. `/bin/cat`).

Just because you can execute it in a login session doesn't mean it will work the same when a daemon like your Java program runs. You have to know what's in your `.bashrc` or `.cshrc` file and even sometimes how the system file is written (`/etc/bashrc`) in order to know how to write a script that runs under a daemon. Another consideration is that daemons often run under the context of a different user, and that throws things off, too.